# Scroll AdvancedDataGrid to keep item in view

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

The following code is working:

item renderer:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    if(editMode)
        dispatchEvent(new Event("editLayoutChange"));
}
```

Datagrid (event handler function for "editLayoutChange" - "viewport" is the AdvancedDataGrid):

```
public function editLayoutChange(event : Event) : void {
    var viewportTopLeft : Point = viewport.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));
    var viewportBottom : Number = viewportTopLeft.y + viewport.height;
    var rendererTopLeft : Point = Container(event.target).localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));
    var rendererBottom : Number = rendererTopLeft.y + Container(event.target).getLayoutBoundsHeight();

    var offset : Number = rendererBottom - viewportBottom; 

    if(offset > 0) {
        // Typical item height is 21px
        var itemHeight : Number = 21;
        matrix.verticalScrollPosition += Math.ceil(offset / itemHeight);
    } 
}
```

But I'm not sure that overriding updateDisplayList is the cleanest implementation as it's firing quite a bit.  I tried dispatching the "editLayoutChange" event in response to the "resize" event on the item renderer, but I'm seeing really erratic behavior.  Is there a better choice for dispatching this event than updateDisplayList?

Edit - I'm listening on updateDisplayList because the renderer will change size (grow) when it enters edit mode, and can expand dynamically during editing.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this kind of thing is to dispatch from `commitProperties` -

In your renderer:

```
private var _editModeEntered:Boolean = false;

private var _editMode:Boolean;
public function set editMode(value:Boolean):void {
    _editMode = true;
    _editModeEntered = true;
    invalidateProperties();
}
// probably want a getter for editMode too

override protected function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();
    if (_enteredEditMode) {
        dispatchEvent(new Event("editLayoutChange"));
        _enteredEditMode = false;
    }
}
```

This ensures the event is dispatched only when you have changed `editMode` explictly.

Comment: The problem is that at the moment "editMode" changes, the renderer has not been resized yet, so it's not possible to perform layout opertions yet.  Also, the size of the renderer may change at a later time after edit mode is activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced Data Grid public API `scrollToIndex(index)` to scroll to the row